# Silencing Rails Console Log for ActionCable Steam

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable

I've connected my channel to an external website steam. All that data is streaming through the console. It's great to see the information that's coming in but is there a way to silence each channel stream from the console?

Answer (score 0):

[as described in the following post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38366040/disable-rails-log-for-actioncable-events#39126977) and tested in my own ActionCable app https://sprachspiel.xyz/

> **in config/environments/development.rb** or **production.rb**
>
> To completely disable logging from ActionCable you should configure ActionCable to use logger that do nothing
>
> `ActionCable.server.config.logger = Logger.new(nil)`

This will remove the following messages and keep the `GET` request to `/cable`

```
Successfully upgraded to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: Upgrade, HTTP_UPGRADE: websocket)
MessagesChannel is transmitting the subscription confirmation
MessagesChannel is streaming from messages
```

Comment: how to remove the GET also?